# Trying to generate an AttributeError without success

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I want to be able to filter an `AttributeError` on a longest code, but I don't understand why it keeps returning me `None` instead of `AttributeError` on this simple code ?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
print(bsObj.randomtest)
```

I'm running Python 3.4.3

Comment: Where is your error handling code?

Comment: @Mike-Müller, here is an extract of the terminal, and it is my problem, I don't have an error code and I don't get why : `nidupmtl:~/workspace/scrapingEnv $ source bin/activate
(scrapingEnv)nidupmtl:~/workspace/scrapingEnv $ python test1.py
None`

Comment: OK. This helps. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, this is how you can catch an `AttributeError`.

```
try:
    ##Do whatever you want that could be caught by an error
except AttributeError:
        print("AttributeError")
```

Answer (score 0):

Diving into the source of `bs4` you will find the reason. The method `__getattr__` of `BeautifulSoup` is implemented, actually inherited form `Tag`. This method is called for every access to a non-existing attribute. This is what happens when you use `randomtest`. This method will be called:

```
def find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None,
         **kwargs):
    """Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given
    criteria."""
    r = None
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
    if l:
        r = l[0]
    return r
```

So, if it cannot find anything it will return `None`.

Comment: @Nidupb Does this make sense for you?